# Html inline-block removing gap

Tags: html, css

So I made a `display: inline-block;` in my css for three elements, I am putting three elements below these elements, but apparently there is a huge gap between them.

I tried putting `display:inline;` instead and after the `display:inline-block;` `height:10px;`

These did not work. How would I remove the gap between these elements?

Comment: Hello, can you create a jsfiddle demo? like this http://jsfiddle.net/unL7ab91/

Comment: you really should search better.. even I already answered this type of questions several times here in SO. if you do a search online here is a good example to solve this issue: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/